# How to install Phoenix OS from Linux?

Tags: linux, grub, iso-image, android-x86

I'm under a Linux Live session (Ubuntu with [Multisystem](https://sourceforge.net/projects/multisystem/)).

Phoenix OS has an .exe installer, installing it in dualboot or multiboot with Linux OS, is not as easy-peasy as with the other x86 based distros (Bliss OS, PrimeOS, etc...), they provide bootable ISO, so the only thing to do is to burn them on a USB stick, and isntall them from there.

As [Phoenix OS](http://www.phoenixos.com/fr/download_x86) provides only an easy way to install the distro inside Windows, with the dedicated installer, I don't know how to burn an ISO for it. I've found ISO, but they don't seem to be bootable. I didn't try with Wine, I doubt it works.

There's a [guide](http://www.phoenixos.com/fr/download_x86) someone wrote, for installing in multiboto with Linux OS, but I'm not able to complete the grub part. It seems too complicate to try the fix the grub errors from my live session. My computer has a functional grub for now, but I get someone /cow errors that I can't fix when I try to upgrade grub or some commands. So, I would need either a way to purge my grub of its error, or to find a way to make the Phoenix ISO bootable.

I think the answers to this question could be useful to the people who try to [install Phoenix OS with Linux](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/92uigs/phoenix_os_bootable_usb/).

On [XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/phoenix-os/phoenix-os-news-qa--development/liveusb-image-t3480211) they say we can boot and use it as a live session, but reading the internet forum, I see I'm not the only one with the non bootable ISO issue. (And if the ISO is bootable, I wonder why they make an installer anyway, maybe they try to make thing simple, but get them more complicated).

Edit: 2 other Phoenix ISO:
files.phoenixos.com/os/Phoenix-x86-1.0-32-beta.zip, from this tuto [here](https://www.frandroid.com/comment-faire/tutoriaux/336321_tuto-comment-installer-phoenix-os-sur-son-pc-windows-10-et-os-x-et-ses-nexus-9-et-10), in French, I burned it with Unetbootin (with the zip file), as the tuto recommend. Result: not bootable. I gave it the "boot" flag, it has a minor improvement, because it found "Phoenix OS", but never boot on it.

I wanted to try this one: https://supreme-gamers.com/resources/phoenixos-darkmatter-supercharged-for-gamers.2/ and this one: https://ghost--official.blogspot.com/2020/03/phoenixos-spectre-edition.html

But I would need guidance, it's pretty hard, this is the install tuto found in the zip (I can't make it a spoiler tag):

> !# FOR NTFS INSTALLTION:
>
> !1) LEGACY USER = INSTALL OFFICIAL PHOENIX OS, COPY THE FILES FROM SPOS ISO >!AND REPLACE THE OFFICIAL FILES
>
> !SYSTEM.IMG, INITRD.IMG, RAMDISK.IMG, KERNEL IN THE PHOENIXOS FOLDER
>
> !2) UEFI USER =  INSTALL OFFICIAL PHOENIX OS, COPY THE FILES FROM SPOS ISO >!AND REPLACE THE OFFICIAL FILES
>
> !SYSTEM.IMG, INITRD.IMG, RAMDISK.IMG, KERNEL IN THE PHOENIXOS FOLDER
>
> !THEN COPY AND REPLACE THE INITRD AND KERNEL FILES IN EFI PARTITION USING >!EXT2FSD AND EXPLORER++
>   !HERE'S A TUTORIAL = https://youtu.be/9NYlWoCQu2g?t=255 (FROM 4:15,THIS PART >!ONLY NECESSARY) (LEGACY USERS NO NEED)
>
> !# FOR EXT4 INSTALLATION:
>
> !1) LEGACY USER = CREATE A NEW NTFS (NECESSARY) PARTITION ATLEAST 25 GB SIZE, >!INSTALL OFFICIAL PHOENIX OS ON THAT DRIVE, (THIS CREATES THE BOOT ENTRY),
>
> !THEN FORMAT THAT DRIVE TO EXT4 USING DISKGENIUS
>
> !NOW, MAKE A FOLDER USING DISKGENIUS NAMED EXACTLY "PhoenixOS" INSIDE YOUR >!EXT4 PARTITION , AND THEN CREATE FOLDER NAMED "data" INSIDE THE "PhoenixOS" >!FOLDER,
>
> !NOW DRAG AND DROP SYSTEM.IMG, INITRD.IMG, RAMDISK.IMG, KERNEL FROM SPOS ISO >!TO "PhoenixOS" FOLDER ON DISKGENIUS, DONE
>
> !2) UEFI USER =
>
> !1) CREATE A NEW NTFS (NECESSARY) PARTITION ATLEAST 25 GB SIZE, INSTALL >!OFFICIAL PHOENIX OS ON THAT DRIVE (THIS CREATES THE BOOT ENTRY),
>
> !THEN FORMAT THAT NTFS DRIVE TO EXT4 USING DISKGENIUS
>
> !2) NOW, USING 7-ZIP OPEN SPECTRE-EDITION ISO AND DRAG AND DROP THESE >!>!FOLLOWING FILES TO ANY NTFS FOR USE IN NEXT STEP: SYSTEM.IMG, INITRD.IMG, RAMDISK.IMG, KERNEL
>
> !3) NOW, MAKE A FOLDER USING DISKGENIUS NAMED EXACTLY "PhoenixOS" INSIDE YOUR >!'EXT4' PARTITION , AND THEN CREATE FOLDER NAMED "data" INSIDE THE >!"PhoenixOS" FOLDER,
>
> !4) NOW DRAG AND DROP SYSTEM.IMG, INITRD.IMG, RAMDISK.IMG, KERNEL FROM 'YOUR >!EXTRACTED LOCATION' TO "PhoenixOS" FOLDER ON DISKGENIUS, DONE
>
> !5) THEN COPY AND REPLACE THE INITRD AND KERNEL FILES IN EFI PARTITION USING >!EXT2FSD AND EXPLORER++
>   !HERE'S A TUTORIAL = https://youtu.be/9NYlWoCQu2g?t=255 (FROM 4:15,THIS PART >!ONLY NECESSARY) (LEGACY USERS NO NEED)
>
> !NOTE: YOU CAN INSTALL WITHOUT THE OFFICIAL INSTALLER TOO, BUT IT MAY BE >!COMPLICATED FOR INEXPERINCED USERS
>
> !IF YOU'RE STUCK AT INITIALIZING IN EXT4, THEN DISKGENIUS COPY-PASTE ISN'T >!WORKING FOR YOU
>
> !TRY USING "EXT2FSD" TO DIRECTLY MOUNT EXT4 TO WINDOWS EXPLORER LINK: >!https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/files/latest/download
>
> !IF YOU'RE HAVING PROBLEMS WITH EXT2FSD SUCH AS SYSTEM FREEZE, YOU CAN USE >!PARAGON EXTFS
>
> !USING THESE YOU CAN PERFORM COPY PASTE NTFS TO EXT4 WITH EASE (WARNING: DONT >!USE BOTH AT THE SAME TIME)
>
> !#ADVANCED INSTALLATION METHOD
>
> !# WITHOUT OFFICIAL INSTALLER, ONLY FOR LEGACY
>
> !1) SKIP THE OFFICIAL INSTALLER PART, BUT FOLLOW OTHER STEPS ACCORDING TO >!YOUR DESIRED PARTITION
>
> !2) COPY THE FILE "phoenixldr" to your C drive, its given.
>
> !3) OPEN BOOTICE>BCD> EASYMODE> ADD REALMODE ENTRY AND CONFIGURE IT LIKE PIC >!1, DONE
>
> !# How to install by USB to Get System as Folder (ONLY IN EXT4)
>
> !1) DOWNLOAD RUFUS FROM OFFICIAL SITE AND BURN THE ISO OF SPOS TO USB DEVICE
>
> !2) THEN USING USB BOOT,  RESTART YOUR WINDOWS
>
> !3) THEN PHOENIX OS INSTALLTION STARTS, CHOOSE INSTALL TO HARDDISK
>
> !4) CHOOSE YOUR DESIRED PARTITION AND FORMAT TO EXT4
>
> !5) SKIP GRUBLOADER AND GRUB2
>
> !6) THIS WILL INSTALL PHOENIXOS TO YOUR HARDDISK
>
> !7) CREATE BOOT ENTRY USING THE ABOVE PROCESS
>
> !# PHOENIX OS BOOT CODE FOR GRUB (FOR LINUX USERS)
>
> ![ search --file --set=root /PhoenixOS/kernel
>   !linux /PhoenixOS/kernel quiet root=/dev/ram0 >!androidboot.hardware=android_x86 SRC=/PhoenixOS vga=788
>   !initrd /PhoenixOS/initrd.img ]
>
> !I KNOW LINUX USERS ARE SMART ENOUGH TO CUSTOMIZE IT FOR OWN FOLDER NAME :)

Comment: Try installing android x86 on which phoenix os is based ; it is much better than phoenix os

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided leads to an ISO-Image which consists of a bootable CD/DVD Image.
I quickly set up a KVM maschine and it booted from it and offered to install the OS into an existing partition or would let you create a partition.
It seems you have to burn a cd/dvd to use that image.

Comment: Thank you, so I used it with the wrong ISO-burning sofwares it seems. I used Multisystem, but it says the ISO is not supported, Etcher and Unetbootin accept it, but Etcher says the ISO is not bootable (works well with other ISOs), Unetbootin creates the USB and says nothing, but the ISO doesn't boot, and shows error message while trying to boot. Thank you very much for your test, you took some of your time for me, and I thank you very much. I will try to find another way to burn the ISO, than with the softwares I used. Maybe the dd command?

Comment: I also tried this one, and failed: http://bbs.phoenixstudio.org/en/showthread.php?tid=3020

Comment: Oh also, maybe the OS works only in a VM? I find many other users on forums with a problem similar (but for this user, it's after install): http://bbs.phoenixstudio.org/en/showthread.php?tid=4651 they give the dd command, I'll try.

Comment: I've just tried this one: http://files.phoenixos.com/os/Phoenix-x86-1.0-32-beta.zip and it cannot boot. I gave it the "boot" flag, and tried again, it seemed a bit improved, as it seacherd for the Phoenix OS, said it found it, but never booted finally. I've found the tuto here (in French): https://www.frandroid.com/comment-faire/tutoriaux/336321_tuto-comment-installer-phoenix-os-sur-son-pc-windows-10-et-os-x-et-ses-nexus-9-et-10